# Сжатие изображений в ios

Tags: android, ios, изображения

Начать стоит с того, что с программирование под ОС iOs я не знаком. Дело в том, что есть программист, который занимается разработкой приложения под эту мобильную систему. Он столкнулся с проблемой сжатия изображения и какие бы ссылки я не скидывал, они ему не подходят, поэтому пришлось обратиться за помощью к Вам.
Если рассматривать алгоритм сжатия изображений под Android, я нашёл его достаточно быстро. Вот он:

```
public static File saveBitmapToFile(File file){
    try {

        // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inSampleSize = 6;
        // factor of downsizing the image

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
        inputStream.close();

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=75;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
        inputStream.close();

        // here i override the original image file
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70 , outputStream);

        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Данный алгоритм сжимает практически любое изображение до 100 Кб! Нужен такой же под iOs. 
Из последних ссылок, которые я скинул(как мне показалось она может решить нашу проблему) он ответил, что api - функция принимает данные в виде файла, а здесь все переводится в NSData([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769968/how-to-compress-image-in-iphone)). И т.к. я далек от этого, то я не смог его слова ни опровергнуть, ни подтвердить. Если из Вас есть человек обладающий достаточными знаниями прошу откликнуться на эту тему!

З.Ы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А сам "программист" обратиться не может? В чем вообще заключается вопрос?

Comment: Сам программист не может, иначе я бы не создавал тему. Вопрос заключается в сжатии изображения.

Comment: Какой именно вопрос? Как сжимать изображения? Как сжимать изображения до 100 кб под иОС? Как сжать изображение, которое NSData? Как сжать изображение, которое не NSData? В тексте нет ни одного вопросительного знака, поэтому совершенно непонятно, в чем заключается вопрос, который "заключается в сжатии изображения".

Comment: Как я понимаю нужно сжать изображение этого типа UIImage. 
Вот эти два вопроса меня особенно интересуют: Как сжимать изображения? Как сжимать изображения до 100 кб под иОС?

Спасибо за понимание.